# Javascript cant get my value and calculate in html

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to do simple calculation for the fee ,but its doesn't work ,there's no error in the code. Did I miss something in the script ?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var bwm = 7.9;
        var bswk = 14;
        var bsbh = 15;
        var wm = 2;
        var swk = 11;
        var sbh = 12;
        var kilo, overkilo, f;
        var s = document.getElementById('place');
        var place = s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;
        var k = document.getElementById('kilo').value;
        var tot;

        function quote() {
            f = document.getElementById('theform');
            f.reset();

            document.getElementById('calc').onclick = function() {
                if (place == 'swk') {
                    (k * swk) + bswk = tot;

                } else if (place == 'sbh') {
                    (k * sbh) + bsbh = tot;

                } else {
                    (k * wm) + bwm = tot;

                }
                document.getElementById('tot').value = 'RM  ' + parseFloat;
            }

        }
    </script>

    <form id="theform" action="#">
        <div>
            <label for="place">Choose Destination :</label>
            <select id="place" onChange="quote()">
                <option value="swk">Sarawak</option>
                <option value="sbh">Sabah</option>
                <option value="wm">WestMalaysia</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="kilo">Amount of KG :</label>
            <input id="kilo" type="text">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Total :</label>
            <input id="tot" type="text" readonly="readonly">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label></label>
            <input id="calc" type="button" value="calculate">
            <input id="r" type="reset" value="clear">
        </div>
    </form>
```

The clear works fine ,but the calculate button won't work even i have input the KG and select a option to calculate .

Comment: How about you use onclick event in inpur#calc selector? You can check on this jsbin snippet. https://jsbin.com/bakebimoho/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Timing is the issue in your code. The form doesn't exist at the time you're trying to get the values. Hit F12 to see error messages. You've to read the values of `place`, `s` and `k` in the change handler too. Or, move the script after the form, and read values of `place` and `k` in the change handler.

Comment: Your code has syntax errors. The left-hand side for assignment should be a variable/property name and not an expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Removed the left-hand side for assignment and set the value.
You defined the var for all instead of that you can use const.
Also form reset not required.

Here is solution of your code

```
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const bwm = 7.9;
        const bswk = 14;
        const bsbh = 15;
        const wm = 2;
        const swk = 11;
        const sbh = 12;
        let kilo, overkilo, f;
       
        var tot;

        function quote() {
        const s = document.getElementById('place');
        const place = s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;
        const k = document.getElementById('kilo').value;
            f = document.getElementById('theform');
            // f.reset();
            document.getElementById('calc').onclick = function() {
                if (place == 'swk') {
                   tot = (k * swk) + bswk;
                } else if (place == 'sbh') {
                   tot = (k * sbh) + bsbh;
                } else {
                    tot = (k * wm) + bwm;
                }
                
                
                document.getElementById('tot').value = 'RM ' + parseFloat(tot);
            }

        }
    </script>

    <form id="theform" action="#">
        <div>
            <label for="place">Choose Destination :</label>
            <select id="place" onChange="quote()">
                <option value="swk">Sarawak</option>
                <option value="sbh">Sabah</option>
                <option value="wm">WestMalaysia</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="kilo">Amount of KG :</label>
            <input id="kilo" type="text">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Total :</label>
            <input id="tot" type="text" readonly="readonly">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label></label>
            <input id="calc" type="submit" value="calculate">
            <input id="r" type="reset" value="clear">
        </div>
    </form>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir ,i have notice what my mistake on my coding , still have a long way to learn about it

Comment: Avoid posting code-only answers, and consider improving your current one by pointing out what you did differently.

Comment: @H.Ryuutoku I just edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the definition of the click handler outside of the change handler, unless the click handler would be defined only when an option changes and also it would be defined on every option change which is unnecessary.

Grab all the required values inside the click handler otherwise you would *not* have the updated values.

And you also need to set the selected index after resetting the form otherwise the change of option would *not* be visible.

```js
const 
  bwm = 7.9,
  bswk = 14,
  bsbh = 15,
  wm = 2,
  swk = 11,
  sbh = 12;

function quote(e) {
  const selIndex = e.target.selectedIndex;
  document.getElementById("theform").reset();
  document.getElementById("place").selectedIndex = selIndex;
}

document.getElementById("calc").onclick = function () {
  const select = document.getElementById("place");
  const place = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
  const k = document.getElementById("kilo").value;
  if (!k) {
    return;
  }
  let tot;
  if (place === "swk") {
    tot = k * swk + bswk;
  } else if (place === "sbh") {
    tot = k * sbh + bsbh;
  } else {
    tot = k * wm + bwm;
  }
  document.getElementById("tot").value = "RM  " + tot;
};
```

```html
<form id="theform" action="#">
  <div>
    <label for="place">Choose Destination :</label>
    <select id="place" onChange="quote(event)">
      <option value="swk">Sarawak</option>
      <option value="sbh">Sabah</option>
      <option value="wm">WestMalaysia</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="kilo">Amount of KG :</label>
    <input id="kilo" type="text">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Total :</label>
    <input id="tot" type="text" readonly="readonly">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label></label>
    <input id="calc" type="button" value="calculate">
    <input id="r" type="reset" value="clear">
  </div>
</form>
```

Instead of resetting the form you could also update the calculated value every time the option changes.

```js
const 
  bwm = 7.9,
  bswk = 14,
  bsbh = 15,
  wm = 2,
  swk = 11,
  sbh = 12;

document.getElementById("calc").onclick = handleClick;

function handleClick() {
  const select = document.getElementById("place");
  const place = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
  const k = document.getElementById("kilo").value;
  if (!k) {
    return;
  }
  let tot;
  if (place === "swk") {
    tot = k * 10 + 10;
  } else if (place === "sbh") {
    tot = k * sbh + bsbh;
  } else {
    tot = k * wm + bwm;
  }
  document.getElementById("tot").value = "RM  " + tot;
}
```

```html
<form id="theform" action="#">
  <div>
    <label for="place">Choose Destination :</label>
    <select id="place" onChange="handleClick()">
      <option value="swk">Sarawak</option>
      <option value="sbh">Sabah</option>
      <option value="wm">WestMalaysia</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="kilo">Amount of KG :</label>
    <input id="kilo" type="text">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Total :</label>
    <input id="tot" type="text" readonly="readonly">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label></label>
    <input id="calc" type="button" value="calculate">
    <input id="r" type="reset" value="clear">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Oh my ,thanks for pointing out my mistake , totally forget about the left-hand side for assignment and set the selected index , thank you

Comment: @H.Ryuutoku I've added another approach that you could consider, you can have a look.